# QuickBooksOnline API - Customer Balance API error - Permission Denied when other non reports API working

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

QuickBooksOnline API - Customer Balance is not working when other non reports API working with same access token

Request

https://sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/123146076363264/reports/CustomerBalance?customer=1

Response

```
{
    "Fault": {
        "Error": [
            {
                "Message": "Permission Denied Error",
                "Detail": "Permission Denied Error : You do not have the access rights to use this feature.",
                "code": "5020",
                "element": "ReportName"
            }
        ],
        "type": "ValidationFault"
    },
    "time": "2019-06-05T05:30:57.879-07:00"
}
```

Comment: I'm running into the same issue. Not sure how to get around this. Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: This happens when you use a wrong report name. I got it to work by using correct file name.